# Perimeter Integrals

Tags: integration

For $r = 1 + \cos \theta, 0 \le \theta < 2\pi$ in 2D polar space calculate the length of $P$, the perimeter by:
$$
\int_P \sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2} \tag{1}
$$
by showing:
$$
(dx)^2 + (dy)^2 = (dr)^2 + (rd\theta)^2.\tag{2}
$$

I am unsure where to go with this. How do I show the 2nd statement and then use it to solve the integral?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$r(\theta)~=~1+\cos(\theta)~=~2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2},$$

so the perimeter is given by

$$ L~=~\int_0^{2\pi} \!{\rm d}\theta~\sqrt{x^{\prime}(\theta)^2+y^{\prime}(\theta)^2}~=~\int_0^{2\pi} \!{\rm d}\theta~\sqrt{r^{\prime}(\theta)^2+r(\theta)^2}~=~\int_0^{2\pi} \!{\rm d}\theta~2\cos\frac{\theta}{2} ~=~8.$$